# Apigee Usergrid: Automatic database trigger based on passage of time

Tags: node.js, apigee, usergrid

I am using Apigee Usergrid to create a car service database. My scenario is as such.
A customer can book his car for a service with his mobile app. This creates a service request in the car service db .

Now, many a times, the customers do not turn up on the booked date and time. In such a case, I want to mark the slot NO-SHOW as soon the stipulated date and time gets over.

As of now, I have a job that runs every day to clear up all such no-shows. But now, we have a requirement to mark such slots NO-SHOW almost as soon as the stipulated hour + 2 passes by.

E.g. if the reservation is on 24th Sept at 0900hrs and the car owner doesn't show up even after 1100hrs, the reservation booking has to be marked NO-SHOW.

Is there a way to achieve this implicitly in user grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't available out of the box. You might try wiring up a Node.js service in Edge (enterprise.apigee.com) to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I can create field level triggers on Edge?

Comment: You'd have to write the logic in Node.js - which is more than capable of all sorts of automation like that.